# Advantages of Multiple Controllers over Single Controller in MVC?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a laravel app and would like to know some best practices.

As an example, I'm thinking about creating multiple controllers instead of writing more than 10 methods in a single controller.

I would like to know what are or( if there are any ) advantages other than code readability.

My main concern is that how does it affect when there are more files to compile by the PHP compiler.

Since I'm using a framework is it going to compile all the files or only the file requested by web.php

Some insight would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 10 methods you have in a controller are all related, then keep them in that controller. If you have a `FruitController` with methods related to performing actions on types of `Fruit`, but you also include some methods for performing actions on `Vegetables`, move the `Vegetable` methods to a new controller.

Consider [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) when composing your files.

In general, avoid making files for the sake of it. If it makes sense to create a new file as the logic you intend to place inside that file has no other existing home, then fine, otherwise add your logic to an existing file.

I'm not sure splitting related code into separate files increases readability, large files can be readable as long as the code is well formatted and consistent (amongst other things). Check out [this book on clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) if you're interested.

What you will get though is a decrease in productivity and maintainability by having to flick through and maintain several files that are all related.

Answer (score 3):

There is no advantage of using multiple controllers instead of one controller, **as long as it is related to one single model**. You may say it increases readability, but this is better to unify them in one single controller which is associated with your model and try to **pick expressive names for the methods**. The main idea is to create one single controller associated with each of your models. Feel free to add as much as methods possible into your models to talk to your database and make queries and call those methods in the associated controller. Then you can trigger those controllers through the `web.php` routes to handle your data and pass them to the view layer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create separate controller for particular functionality this is more readable for old and new developer. 
Also please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114249/in-laravel-what-is-the-advantage-of-single-action-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

From laravel:

```
Instead of defining all of your request handling logic as Closures in route files, you
may wish to organize this behavior using Controller classes. Controllers can group 
related request handling logic into a single class. Controllers are stored in the 
app/Http/Controllers directory.
```

I recommend that you divide your logic into different controllers. For example you can place all your user logic into one controller ***userController.php***:

1. Create User
2. Edit User
3. Delete User

Then create another controller to manage the logic for another controller like sending emails etc. In this way your logic is more organized, easy to work with and you can find and update your methods easier.